# Best practice for deploying Office 2016 VSTO Addins

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

We have developed some in house toolbars for Office 2016 and want to deploy them to all our users.

At present, the VSTO builds to an EXE, which we can deploy using Group Policy. Once installed the Addin shows up in Add / Remove Programs (Windows 10).

However, we wish to future proof this, so that we can roll out newer versions of the toolbars when we make updates.

Using the Group Policy method, we end up with multiple versions of the EXE installed. (Only one is actually present in the applications, but you can see both in Add / Remove Programs).

How should we package up these addins so that we can roll out future versions (either by GPO or script)? I suspect MSI may be the way to go, but this is new territory for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my VSTO add-ins, I deploy via ClickOnce. ClickOnce has the huge advantage of automatically checking for updates when the user opens the corresponding Office application.

Of course, ClickOnce is difficult to deploy via Group Policy (although solutions do exist). One thing you could look at is creating a ClickOnce bootstrapper executable (setup.exe generated using MSBuild), and deploy this via Group Policy instead.

You can generate a bootstrapper in one of two ways; either in Visual Studio (Project Properties, Publish, Prerequisites, Create setup program to install prerequisite components) or programmatically using the Microsoft.Build namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Logging;
using Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

public class BootstrapperExample {
    private string GenerateBootstrapper(string manifestFile, string applicationName, string applicationUrl, params string[] prerequisites) {
        // root element
        ProjectRootElement xml = ProjectRootElement.Create();
        xml.ToolsVersion = "4.0";
        xml.DefaultTargets = "BuildBootstrapper";

        // build properties
        var propertyGroup = xml.AddPropertyGroup();
        propertyGroup.AddProperty("TargetFrameworkVersion", "v4.5");
        propertyGroup.AddProperty("VisualStudioVersion", "11.0");

        // prerequisites (product codes of each required package, e.g. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5")
        var itemGroup = xml.AddItemGroup();
        foreach (string productCode in prerequisites) {
            itemGroup.AddItem("BootstrapperFile", productCode);
        }

        // target
        var target = xml.AddTarget("BuildBootstrapper");
        var task = target.AddTask("GenerateBootstrapper");
        task.SetParameter("ApplicationFile", Path.GetFileName(manifestFile));
        task.SetParameter("ApplicationName", applicationName);
        task.SetParameter("ApplicationUrl", applicationUrl);
        task.SetParameter("BootstrapperItems", "@(BootstrapperFile)");
        task.SetParameter("OutputPath", Path.GetDirectoryName(manifestFile));
        task.SetParameter("Path", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper");     // replace with actual path

        var proj = new ProjectInstance(xml);
        var req = new BuildRequestData(proj, new string[] { "BuildBootstrapper" });
        var parameters = new BuildParameters();

        // optional logging of the build process
        var logger = new FileLogger();
        Uri codeBase = new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
        logger.Parameters = "logfile=" + Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(codeBase.LocalPath), "msbuild.log");
        parameters.Loggers = new ILogger[] { logger };

        // build the bootstrapper executable (setup.exe)
        var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(parameters, req);
        if (result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Failure) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("MSBuild task failed!", result.Exception);
        }

        // return path to the built setup.exe
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(manifestFile), "setup.exe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that could be ideal for us. Can you point me in the right direction for how to create a ClickOnce package?

Comment: @Ben I've updated my answer to include the two methods I know of.